# Complex search in filmemaker using scripts ( (A or B) and (C or D or E) )

Tags: search, operators, filemaker

I have a filemaker database and I want to show records based on the following criteria:

Show all records in which either the owner or the user is "John" and the place is "London", "Paris" or "Amsterdam"

The first part is easy:

```
Enter Find Mode [Pause:Off]
Set Field [mydb::Owner; "John"]
New Record/Request
Set Field [mydb::User"; "John"]
Perform Find[]
```

But what about the second part? So far I have not been able to implement this. I could of course go ahead and loop through the records found and omit the ones I don't want, but there should be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is. You can use the Constrain Found Set after you perform your initial find.

```
Enter Find Mode [Pause:Off]
Set Field [mydb::Owner; "John"]
New Record/Request
Set Field [mydb::User"; "John"]
Perform Find[]
#Constrain the found set
Enter Find Mode [Pause:Off]
Set Field [mydb::Place; "London"]
New Record/Request
Set Field [mydb::Place; "Paris"]
New Record/Request
Set Field [mydb::Place; "Amsterdam"]
Constrain Found Set []
```

Comment: Quick follow up question. How to omit records? What if I want (A or B) and (C or D or E) and not F and not G?

Comment: You use the same procedure. Add find criteria but add the omit record script step to each criteria you wish to exclude.

Answer (score 1):

One straightforward way to create FileMaker searches is to rephrase your search-requirements in a list like this:

```
(O and L)
or
(O and P)
or
(O and A)
or
(U and L)
or
(U and P)
or
(U and A)
but not
(B and C)
```

In other words:

1. For *each case* that you want to find, you write down the criteria seperated by 'and' in one line. You can add parentheses, which are optional, but they do make it easier to read & understand the logic correctly
2. Then you separate each line with an 'or'
3. And if you have cases that you want to *exclude* from the results you write 'but not' instead of 'or', and - very importantly - you add the exclusions at the END of the list!

In your example, you could write:

```
(Owner="John" and Place="London")
or
(Owner="John" and Place="Paris")
or
(Owner="John" and Place="Amsterdam")
or
(User="John" and Place="London")
or
(User="John" and Place="Paris")
or
(User="John" and Place="Amsterdam")
```

When you have this written down, all you then have to do is:

1. Replace each criteria with the equivalent Set Field step (and otherwise ignore the 'and's)
2. Replace 'or' with a New Record/Request step
3. Replace 'but not' with the two steps New Record/Request, Omit Record
4. Put all that in an Enter Find Mode [Pause:Off] / Perform Find[] sandwich, and you are ready to run!

The example code then looks like this:

```
Enter Find Mode [Pause:Off]
Set Field [mydb::Owner ; "John"]
Set Field [mydb::Place ; "London"]
New Record/Request
Set Field [mydb::Owner ; "John"]
Set Field [mydb::Place ; "Paris"]
New Record/Request
Set Field [mydb::Owner ; "John"]
Set Field [mydb::Place ; "Amsterdam"]
New Record/Request
Set Field [mydb::User ; "John"]
Set Field [mydb::Place ; "London"]
New Record/Request
Set Field [mydb::User ; "John"]
Set Field [mydb::Place ; "Paris"]
New Record/Request
Set Field [mydb::User ; "John"]
Set Field [mydb::Place ; "Amsterdam"]
Perform Find[]
```

Whether you use this multiple-request method or AndreasT's constrain method is a question of performance & the quantity of combinations you have got.

For the sake of completeness, here is an example of 'but not' - with a Brexit theme:

Say you are wanting to find FileMaker programmers in continental europe, you may have the following criteria:

```
(Job="FileMaker" and Place="Europe")
but not
(Land="UK")
```

Using the above method this would then be implemented as:

```
Enter Find Mode [Pause:Off]
Set Field [mydb::Job ; "FileMaker"]
Set Field [mydb::Place ; "Europe"]
New Record/Request
Omit Record
Set Field [mydb::Land ; "UK]
Perform Find[]
```

Happy FileMaking!

MrWatson

Comment: MrWatson: Nice alternative. I do think I will stick with AndreasT's solution though. The think with your alternative is that the code is not as easy to maintain (for example if you add a constraint or remove one)

Comment: Did you know, whichever method you use, it is possible to GENERATE the code. Just perform the search manually, then add a Perform Find Script [ Restore ] ... and if you want the *expanded* code you can download fmWorkMate, convert the step to XML with fmCheckMate and then transform the XML with the "Explode Find" transformation -> it's really cool.